# Equivalence or conversion matrix between .NET 4.0 Async CTP terms and their .NET 4.5 analogs?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0, async-ctp

I am using [Async CTP (Version 3)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9983) + [SP1 to it](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28568) for developing and testing in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 on Windows XP SP3 mainly because my clients (as well as I) are on Windows XP SP3. See related topics:

- on MSDN forum: ["If I target .net 4.0 but run on a machine that has .net 4.5 will .net 4.0 WPF bugs still be there?"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c05a8c02-de67-47a9-b4ed-fd8b622a7e4a/)
- my question on SO: ["What are the major risks vs. benefits of using VS2010 Async CTP??"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873354/what-are-the-major-risks-vs-benefits-of-using-vs2010-async-ctp)

Let me cite here from [Async CTP (Version 3)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9983) download page:

> Includes a new EULA for production use. Note - This license does not
>   constitute encouragement for you to use the CTP for your production
>   code. The CTP remains an unsupported and use-at-your-own-risk
>   Technology Preview. **However, we’ve received many requests from
>   developers to use the CTP for production code**, and so have changed
>   the license to allow that.

All MSDN docs and code samples online about .NET 4.5 (C# 5.) as well as what is new in them.
Currently, when they fail for my .NET 4.0+VS2010, I am searching through installed with Async CTP `<My Documents>\Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP\Samples` for .NET 4.0 + VS2010.  I could not find any a conversion or comparison matrix or a list of differences (changes), between C# 4.0 (.NET 4.0, VS2010) and Async extensions and C# 5.0 (.NET 4.5 + VS 2012) or just articles

Is there any equivalence or conversion matrix between?
What are the known differences?

Related question:

- [What is the difference between `TaskEx.Run()` and `TaskEx.RunEx()` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334818/when-to-use-taskex-run)

Comment: `TaskEx` was introduced because you cannot add static extension methods.